# Meteor Blaze display array

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

I have collections like this:

[image]

I want to iterate over object.questions.teema for example.

I have helper:

```
Template.game.helpers({
    theGame: function() {
        var theGame = Game.findOne({_id:"LhQmaZKW8eJNenyX9"})
        console.log(theGame)
        return theGame
    }
});
```

and template:

```
<template name="game">

{{#with theGame}}
  {{#each theGame.questions}}
    {{teema}}
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
</template>
```

But it doesnt work, what is wrong with the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'#each theGame.questions' Will not work inside the #with, because you can access the 'theGame' object directly.

The point is when you try to get theGame object inside the #with it will return you undefined, because 'theGame' object does not have theGame property, Which you want to access inside #with block.

```
<template name="game">
  {{#with theGame}}
    {{#each questions}}
       //Thie #each because you have nested array. As I can see in your console log.
       {{#each this}}
         {{teema}}
       {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

`theGame.questions` is an array (that you iterate over) of array of objects which have the `teema` key. So you still need to iterate over the 2nd level array, or define a specific item in that array before you can eventually reach the object with `teema` property.

Maybe something like:

```spacebars
{{#with theGame}}
  {{#each questions}}
    {{#each this}}
      {{this.teema}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

But it depends on why you have these 2-level arrays in the first place.

Comment: So something like this:

{{#with theGame}}
  {{#each theGame.questions}}
    {{#each questions.teema}}
      {{teema}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
 
This doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Nope. Edited answer with a tentative code. Check first why you ever need those 2-levels arrays...

Comment: That was good suggestion, I didn't need 2 level arrays. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is `{{teema}}` supposed to be?

Regardless, as you can see from your console.log statement, {{theGame.questions}} returns another array. But that array returns objects. This is really hard to query for with Blaze.

The better solution would be to flatten it out so that your data is shaped like this:

```
questions: [
   {
       a: 'asdfkjah',
       level: 'askdjfhal',
       q: 'asdkfh',
       teema: 'asdkfjh'
       vaartus: 100
   },
   {
      ...
   }
]
```

This way you don't have an array nested in an array. That will allow you to:

```
{{#with theGame}}
  {{#each theGame.questions}}
    {{this.teema}}
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```